# Using SVG files like PNG files in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, svg, windows-phone-8

I have googled for some answers, but it didn't come up with anything of use for me.
Is it possible to use svg files like png (jpeg, or any other raster graphic format) in Image control in Windows Phone 8? With the result similar to the following (not working) code:

```
<Image Margin="0,0,0,-19" Source="/Assets/SVG/image.svg" 
Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think SVG is natively supported in Windows Phone (except, perhaps, in IE10 mobile). However, you can easily convert an SVG image to XAML, using tools like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

Comment: Yeah, converting to XAML is the solution that is widely spread over the stackoverflow. However you have answered my question, so thank you. Yet, the question remains open, in case some example code of using xaml-converted svg file shows up.

Comment: Michael you can keep it open as long as you want. The support isn't there. Not sure SVG support is a priority for #WP9 or #WP10 so you might be waiting for a long time here

Comment: @JitendraVyas, I just tried, and it works in mine... (Nokia Lumia 920)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - I'm using SVG icon fonts made from http://icomoon.io/ and my Nokia Lumia 720 not showing icons but Android mobile it's fine

Comment: @JitendraVyas, just tried again with a SVG from this site, and it works

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Thanks for checking. Are you loading icons from SVG or font in windows mobile? And if you are using SVG then pls test if it's working even after we use this fix http://icomoon.io/#blog/post1

Comment: @JitendraVyas, I'm just displaying a page with `<img src="something.svg"/>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33556/discussion-between-jitendra-vyas-and-thomas-levesque)

Comment: @JitendraVyas, sorry, no time